# how to connect a .php file with a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

i've written the following code:

```
$db_user = 'bushra';  
$db_pass = '12';
$db_host ='localhost';  
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

but it shows the error:

> > Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'bushra'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\no.php on line 7

root have no password here.i've created a user named bushra

Comment: Try resetting the password with phpmyadmin

Comment: is the password for user bushra correct ??

Comment: Your password is wrong.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Either your username or your password or both are wrong. ;)

Comment: when we add a table where it will be saved i mean under which user! and if root has no password the what will be the parameters of mysql_connect()? pls help............................

Comment: For goodness sake, **set a root password**!

Answer (score 1):

Your password is wrong. You can either connect using `root` like this:

```
$db_user = 'root';  
$db_pass = '';
$db_host ='localhost';  
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Or you can re-create your user `bushra`. Maybe you had a typo? Or maybe you forgot to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` after creating the user?

Answer (score 1):

check first if you have the correct privileges on your mysql database, if you have for example a database named db, try this

```
grant select privileges on db.* to bushra@localhost identified by '12';
```

or
    `grant select privileges on db.* to bushra@% identified by '12';`

Comment: I like to do `grant select privileges on db.* to 'bushra'@'127.0.0.1' identified by '12';` as well, since MySQL sometimes treats 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' differently (one uses a socket, and the other opens a port).

Answer (score 0):

you either have no password or use a wrong one

Answer (score 0):

This message means that the password is incorrect. Try this instead if the root has empty password:

```
$db_user = 'root';  
$db_pass = '';
$db_host ='localhost';  
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with root user itself if you want :

```
$db_user = 'root';  
$db_pass = '';
$db_host ='localhost';  
mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
```

If you are sure your user **bushra** password is **12**, then you need to **restart mysql** before trying.

Hope this helps you :)

Answer (score -1):

I think if you have no password, you don't have to write $db_pass

Comment: If you have no password, you should set one.

Comment: I know that. But he was asking why his code wasn't working, not how he could secure his website.